# Convection and gravity waves?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science, convection

Quote from Wikipedia article on ["stratosphere"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratosphere)

> "An interesting feature of stratospheric circulation is the quasi-biennial oscillation (QBO) in the tropical latitudes, which is driven by gravity waves that are convectively generated in the troposphere. The QBO induces a secondary circulation that is important for the global stratospheric transport of tracers, such as ozone[8] or water vapor."

Further googling on "gravity waves and convection" provides articles related to "QBO". I can't seem to find anything about the phenomenon itself.

So how can convection cause distortions in gravitational fields?

Links are welcome.

Comment: [gravity waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave) and [gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) are entirely different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gravity waves are not gravitational waves. They are waves that can exist in a fluid in the presence of a gravitational field. In their simplest form, their phase velocity is proportional to the square root of the gravity acceleration. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave